# How can I change an image using a button in android studio?

Tags: android

I am doing a project that requires me to change an image in the same form content page with a button onclick or another button method if you have one. I normally program in C# with visual studio and I am not used to the java so I would greatly appreciate it, Thank you.

Comment: in your setOnClicklistener of button, write code which change the imageview you want to change, for example if your imageView name is ivIcon you should write : ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image)

Comment: Please do not use the [android-studio] tag for general Android programming questions. The correct tag is [android]. The [android-studio] tag is for questions specific to the functionality of that IDE.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to explain exactly what issues you're having in implementing your described design. There are many examples here already that demonstrate how to do what you're asking. We need to know which parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: I did my question was for it as a hole because I did not know exactly what to do I did not know if I had to do it just in the code so I could not specify but Mohammad Hadi answered it perfectly for me I think.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample image changer code

Xml -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/changeBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="151dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="172dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:onClick="change"
    android:text="Change"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="456dp"
    android:layout_height="632dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cats01" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int i =0;

public void change(View view)
{


    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cats01); // this function 
        changes the image 







}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
  }
```